# JSTL timezone (KST) implementation error found

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset, jstl-functions

While I practicing JSTL timeZone tag, I tried to run these two actions:

```
<c:set var="now" value="<%= new java.util.Date() %>" />
<fmt:timeZone value="GMT+9:00">
    <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" type="both"
                    dateStyle="full" timeStyle="full"/>
</fmt:timeZone>
<%-- and --%>
<fmt:timeZone value="KST">
    <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" type="both"
                    dateStyle="full" timeStyle="full"/>
</fmt:timeZone>
```

I believe they should produce same result. However, they produce following two different time values.

2017년 8월 15일 화요일 오후(PM) 8시 03분 27초 GMT+09:00

2017년 8월 15일 화요일 오전(AM) 11시 03분 27초 GMT

Did I miss something or the implementation is incorrect?
I case of mis-implementation, who should I contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to use  three-letter time zone IDs. They are deprecated. And not all of them are supported.

See [oracle java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

> Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone
>   IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their
>   use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for
>   multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central
>   Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can
>   then only recognize one of them.

Answer (score 2):

`GMT+09:00` is not a timezone, it's a [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC): a difference (in hours, minutes and seconds) from [**UTC**](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html). It just means "9 hours ahead of UTC", and it's not attached to any specific region or country. (most systems, though, usually treats the offset as a "special type" of timezone, just to [make things easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756430/why-utc-which-is-not-a-time-zone-is-considered-as-a-time-zone-in-java-and-not/44760188#44760188)).

`KST` is an [abbreviation for Korea Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/kst), but is not a "true" timezone. Timezones names are not really standardized, but many systems use [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `Asia/Seoul` or `Europe/London`).
The use of the short abbreviations (like `CST` or `KST`) is usually avoided by systems because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

The timezone `Asia/Seoul` uses `KST` abbreviation today, but this was also used in the past by `Asia/Pyongyang`. Though, they're not the same zone.

A timezone is a set of all different offsets that a region had, has and will have during its history. Today `Asia/Seoul` uses the `+09:00` offset, but  `Asia/Pyongyang` also used in the past, so their historical data are different (and that's why they are distinct zones).

Pyongyang had the [`+08:30` offset until 1912](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/north-korea/pyongyang), when changed to `+09:00`. But in 2015 it changed again to `+08:30` and it's using it until today.

Seoul has a [different offset history](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/south-korea/seoul?year=1980): it also used `+08:30` in the past (in the 50's), with Daylight Saving Time (change to `+09:30` during summer), then in 1961 it changed to `+09:00`, had DST during some time, and today is using just `+09:00` without DST.

All these changes are defined by governments and laws, and systems have no control over it. Just because a timezone (a region) uses some offset today, there's no guarantee that it'll use this forever.
So, although `KST` can be a "synonym" of `+09:00` today, it doesn't mean it'll be like that forever.

---

So, when you use `GMT+09:00`, you're using just the offset, without any correlation to a specific timezone (because [there are lots of timezones that can use this offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)).

In the second case, it seems that the date is being converted from `KST` (offfset `+09:00`) to UTC (offset zero, or "GMT"). Note that the first case is 8 PM in offset `+09:00` and the second is 11 AM in UTC (offset zero, or "GMT"), which is correct.

Maybe JSTL can't recognize `KST` (because of its ambiguity) and uses UTC as a default. I'd try to replace it with `Asia/Seoul` and see what happens.