# How to Pick Timezone from ISO 8601 format String into a Calendar instace

Tags: java, android, date, datetime-parsing, java.util.calendar

As an input I have a string which is a String in ISO 8601 to represent date. For example:

> "2017-04-04T09:00:00-08:00"

The last part of `String`, which is **"-08:00"** denotes TimeZone Offset. I convert this string into a `Calendar` instance as shown below:

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US).parse(iso8601Date);
calendar.setTime(date);
```

**iso8601Date is "2017-04-04T09:00:00-08:00"**

But this does not pick timezone and if I get timezone from `Calendar` instance, it gives currently set instance of the laptop and does not pick up timestamp from ISO 8601 String. I check for timezone via calendar instance as:

```
calendar.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()
```

Can someone show how to pick timezone also in the `Calendar` instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `Calendar`, it takes the JVM's default timezone. And when you parse a `String` to a `Date`, it just sets one value: the number of milliseconds since epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`). A `Date` [doesn't have any timezone information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/), just this milliseconds value. So you need to set the timezone in the calendar.

In your formatter, you're treating `Z` as a literal, because it's inside quotes (`'Z'`). This ignores the offset and gets the date in the JVM default timezone (which will have a different value if the corresponding offset is not -08:00).

In JDK >= 7, you can use the `X` pattern to parse the offset:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.US).parse(iso8601Date);
```

But this doesn't set the timezone in the calendar (it will still use the JVM's default). So, a "better" way is to strip the offset from the input and handle it separately:

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
String iso8601Date = "2017-04-04T09:00:00-08:00";
// get the offset (-08:00)
String offset = iso8601Date.substring(19);
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + offset);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
// set the offset in the formatter
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
// parse just date and time (without the offset)
Date date = sdf.parse(iso8601Date.substring(0, 19));
// set the offset in the calendar
calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
calendar.setTime(date);
```

With this, the calendar will have the offset `-08:00` set. As [@BasilBourque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059135/7605325) already said, [`-08:00` is an offset, not a timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44760188/7605325) (the `TimeZone` class treats offsets just like they were timezones, which is a workaround/bad design choice).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

In Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. You'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to make it work (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

[@BasilBourque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059135/7605325) already tells you about `OffsetDateTime`. But to convert to a `Calendar`, you can use a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime` and convert it using the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class:

```
String iso8601Date = "2017-04-04T09:00:00-08:00";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(iso8601Date);
Calendar cal = DateTimeUtils.toGregorianCalendar(zdt);
```

The calendar will be already set with the `-08:00` offset.

---

If you want to get the timezone from the offset, I'm afraid it's not that simple. More than one timezone [can use the same offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), so you can't know for sure which timezone to use (the best you can do is to get a list of possible candidates).

---

## java.util.Date

Just a more detailed note about `java.util.Date`. [This link](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) explains a lot about it, so I really recommend you to read it.

As already said above, a `Date` has no timezone information. It just keeps the number of milliseconds since epoch (which is `1970-01-01T00:00Z`, or **January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at midnight in UTC**).

This value is the same everywhere in the world. Example: at the moment I'm writing this, the millis value for the current time is `1504632865935`. This number is the same for anyone in the world who gets the current time at the same instant I did, regardless of what timezone they're using.

What is different is the **local date and time** that corresponds to this millis value. In UTC, it corresponds to `2017-09-05T17:34:25.935Z`, in New York, the date is the same (September 5<sup>th</sup> 2017) but the time is different (13:34), and in Tokyo is September **6<sup>th</sup>** 2017 at 02:34 AM.

Although the `Date` object is the same (because its millis value is `1504632865935` for everyone), the **corresponding** date and time changes according to the timezone used.

People tend to think that a `Date` has a timezone because when printing it (with `System.out.println` or by loggging) or when inspecting in a debugger, it implicity uses the `toString()` method, and this converts the date to the JVM's default timezone (and it also prints the zone name). This gives the impression that a `Date` has a format and a timezone set to it, but it doesn't.

Comment: I wish i could Plus one more than once.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-04-04T09:00:00-08:00" )
```

## Details

> The last part of String which is "-08:00" denotes TimeZone Offset.

Do not confuse offset with time zone.

The `-08:00` represents an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), not a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). A time zone is a history of various offsets used in the past, present, and future by the people of a particular region. A time zone is named with a continent, slash, and region such as [`America/Los_Angeles`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Los_Angeles) or `Pacific/Auckland` or [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata).

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. For Android, see the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) projects.

Your input indicates only offset but not zone. So we parse as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-04-04T09:00:00-08:00" ) ;
```

If you are absolutely certain of the intended time zone, assign it.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I agree, stay away from `java.util.Date` (unless absolutely required by some other API *and* you're working in local time zone).

Comment: @EugenPechanec Actually, `java.util.Date` is always in UTC so your own time zone would be irrelevant. Both `Date` and `Calendar` classes are such a wretched mess that I advise *always* steering clear of them; always use java.time or its back-port. When the legacy classes are required by another API, do your own work in java.time, then convert results. To convert in Java 8 and later, look to new methods added to the old classes, in the back-port look to a utility class with conversion methods.

Comment: I read about java.time.OffsetDateTime but it is not available to android.

Comment: @Terri See the back-port projects linked in my Answer. Well worth the bother of adding a library to your project.

Comment: @BasilBourque As part of returning individual fields (`getHour()`, `getDay()`, etc.) the calendar gets "normalized" to current time zone. So if you constructed the Date object with the millis constructor (i.e. in UTC), you'd get garbage, unless your local TZ is UTC. If you constructed the Date object using individual fields, you'd get garbage if your local TZ is different. In conclusion it's not UTC and not even local TZ. It's an indeterminate bloody mess.

Answer (score 1):

One Key understanding I want to share from Hugo's answer and my further search is following. Please correct me if I am wrong:

Date does not care about timezone. It represents milliseconds passed since epoch.

Regarding finding the Timezone from provided ISO 8061 format is there, Date class can not tell that and we have to use some alternate methods as specified by @Hugo and @Basil Bourque.

Comment: Not exactly. A  `Date` has the number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z` (also called "unix epoch", or *Jan 1st 1970 midnight in UTC*). Suppose this number of milliseconds is 1491325200000. This number represents a different date and time in each timezone. It can be `2017-04-04 at 5 PM in UTC`, or 1 PM in New York or the next day (`2017-04-05`) at 2 AM in Tokyo. A  `Date` is not aware of the date/time fields (it doesn't have day/month/year, nor hour/minute/second - those fields will have different values in different timezones - as the date has no timezone, it doesn't have the fields).

Comment: When you say *"milliseconds represents for example: 1st January 2017 02:00"*, you must also ask: "where?" (in which timezone?). This date and time can represent a different number of milliseconds since epoch, depending on the timezone you use. If you consider Jan 1st 2017 at 2 AM in UTC, the millis value is `1483236000000`. But the same date/time in New York corresponds to millis `1483254000000`, and in Tokyo is `1483203600000`. The millis value is the only "absolute" value (it's the same everywhere), but the local date/time that corresponds to it depends on the timezone.

Comment: I've added some info about it in my answer.